# How is the rear USB port of a car stereo system supposed to be used?

Tags: audio

For a 2011 Toyota Corolla which doesn't come with an USB port pre-installed, I am looking for a car stereo system (to replace the factory default one) equipped with an USB port. Amazon lists a bunch of such stereo systems which come with one or more rear USB ports. What doesn't make any sense to me how one is supposed to use such an USB port located at the back of the unit after it is installed in the front deck. Can anyone enlighten me? Am I really supposed to drill through the front deck to extend a cable to the rear port? That sounds like a terrible idea and I hope I am wrong! Can anybody provide me a picture showing how to reach such a rear USB port after installation? Is a front USB port better in term of usability?

Answer (score 2):

While much of what you're asking about is subjective, I'll answer the main thing going on here, which is what's going on with the USB port in the back. The simple answer is, if there's a rear USB port, the manufacturer will most likely include the USB extension with the head unit. You can place the extension to any place you want to. I've found it very easy to place it at some point where the dash molding meets the body with just the end sticking out. Some place inconspicuous which allows easy access. I've never drilled a hole for it as it wasn't needed. You run the cable during installation with the dash molding removed. It is fairly easy.

From there, I've usually put a thumb drive with my music on it. You could also (I'd assume) attach any other USB enabled device, like an iPhone or Android phone, using the port. Sky's the limits ... whatever your head unit can deal with. This isn't a hard process ... you just have to plan where you're going to have the USB cable hanging out. It could be completely hidden, or completely obvious. This would be your choice.

Comment: Often you can reach the glove compartment pretty easily from the stereo mount, often without drilling, that's where I put my extension

Comment: @GdD - I've put mine near the glove compartment, but you are exactly right. The USB extensions I've used are about 2' in length (~61cm), so can reach pretty easily (probably a bit long, actually).

Comment: @GdD Is it possible to share a picture of how the final assembly looks like?

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock, I'm afraid I never took any pictures of my installation. Plus, my car is a BMW, so it wouldn't help you much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a tiny usb stick into it permanently.

Or you could put a usb hard drive on a cable and mount the hard drive close.

Or you could put a long usb cable into it and route the cable to where it might be useful - for the kids perhaps...

There are many options.